# Can converting NFA to DFA change the language?

Tags: finite-automata, nondeterminism

In the context of studying the conversion from an NFA to the equivalent DFA, I came across the following NFA, which accepts all strings over the alphabet $\{0,1\}$ which contain $01$:

[image]

After I converted the NFA to the equivalent DFA, it became:

[image]

The issue is that the NFA accepts the string $101$ but the DFA doesn't.

Is my conversion wrong or is there something I am missing about the NFA to DFA conversion?

Comment: How does the NFA accept `101`? I think the NFA only accepts words starting with `01`.

Comment: I think your NFA might be missing a self-loop in the initial state (currently your NFA is also a DFA).

Comment: As @Shaull pointed currently your NFA is also an [incomplete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_finite_automaton#Complete_and_incomplete) DFA and the DFA you obtained after conversion is the complete version of the NFA (or DFA)

Comment: If the language by your DFA differs from the language accepted by your NFA then you did something wrong during the conversion.

Comment: Two automata are equivalent, *by definition*, if they accept the same language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By definition, two automata are equivalent if they accept the same language.

In your case, the DFA you construct is indeed equivalent to the NFA you start with. Both of them accept all strings starting with $01$. In particular your NFA does *not* accept $101$.